# Screen height depending on theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have layout with **centered Image View**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/WHITE">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/powered_by"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="70%"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Here is theme setting for my activity

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

When i change parent theme to `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light`, **ImageView appears a little bit higher, not in center of the screen**. It seems like parent view for my device now starts not from the bottom of the screen, but from the bottom toolbar (i use Nexus 5X with on-screen buttons).

I want to use device default theme for a modern dialog appearance, but i also need to have this image view exactly in center on all devices.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light` is not setting `android:windowFullScreen`. So you will need to create your own theme with the parent `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light` and change the values for the items you want to change

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, unfortunately. I have used the same style, Image View is not centered with this.

Comment: Will need to post the layout code then to see if the problem is there